# I am trying to work with excel files with aspose cell so that I can encrypted them but its not working because of Java

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, aspose-cells

```
import jpype
import asposecells
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import *
```

for this code, I get the following error

JVMNotFoundException: No JVM shared library file (jvm.dll) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly.

I am doing this through anaconda, in jupyter notebook. I am trying to get the workbook from aspose cell.

Answer (score 0):

It seems configuration issue. Try to setup your environment properly. Make sure to install Java and setup JAVA_HOME and Path environment variables accordingly, see the document on how to [setup environment and installation](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/python-java/setup-environment-and-installation-guidelines/) to use Aspose.Cells for Python via Java for your reference. You may also post your queries in the dedicated [section](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.